# How to create Application in the IIS Default Web Site root (virtual path : '/')?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

**Context**

I have an Asp.Net MVC application. I would like to deploy it to an IIS (Windows Server 2016). I do not care which will be physical path, but I would like to access to the application in the virtual path '/'

(I am using Package web publish method, because no online access to the server, but I think this question is on IIS/ASP and not about publishing. I clearly miss some basic concept about IIS/ASP.)

**What I've tried**

1) When I try to create an Application in IIS then the dialog forces me to add an application Alias, which becomes the part of the virtual path. So regardless the physical path now the the url will be

myserver/myapp/mypage instead of myserver/mypage

which is not what I want. I would like to access to the page as **myserver/mypage**

2) If I simply deploy the app under wwwroot then it will appear as myserver/mypage it seems to be working, but where is the "Application" this case? (see picture).

**Question**

Maybe I missing something: Is this the Default Web Site is an "Application" in its own right?  How to configure then its Application settings? If not, then how can I create an Application which's virtual path is '/'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to access the application as servername/pagename. In order to do so, do not create an "application" or "virtual directory" under a "website". Instead, directly host the content under Default website. You can change its path under "Basic Settings" and point it to your content folder.

You can also create another website at port 80 and point it to the location where your content is present. However, you will not be allowed to create 2 website with the same IP-port-hostname combination. You can solve this problem further in 3 ways.

1. If Default web site is not in use, then instead of creating another website, click on Default website, select basic setting from right hand panel and change the path to application content folder.
2. If Default website is in use, then create another another website at port 80 with a hostname.
3. If you do not have a hostname and are accessing the application using server-name, then you will have to modify the port to 8080 or something like that.

Refer my blog - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/07/27/iis-bindings/ for more information about IIS bindings